# Understanding dependencies in an R package

Tags: r

I'm (very) new to the R world, coming from a JS world, and learning to create [htmlwidgets for R](https://www.htmlwidgets.org/). I ran through the [*Creating a widget* tutorial](https://www.htmlwidgets.org/develop_intro.html), and got it working, however apparently I'm not understanding something about dependencies.

This is the package structure the tutorial calls for.

```
R/
| sigma.R

inst/
|-- htmlwidgets/
|   |-- sigma.js
|   |-- sigma.yaml
|   |-- lib/
|   |   |-- sigma-1.0.3/
|   |   |   |-- sigma.min.js
|   |   |   |-- plugins/
|   |   |   |   |-- sigma.parsers.gexf.min.js
```

This is the package structure of the repo from [jjallaire/sigma on Github](https://github.com/jjallaire/sigma).

```
|____.DS_Store
|____.gitignore
|____.Rbuildignore
|____DESCRIPTION
|____inst
| |____.DS_Store
| |____examples
| | |____.gitignore
| | |____ediaspora-shiny.R
| | |____ediaspora.gexf.xml
| | |____ediaspora.R
| | |____ediaspora.Rmd
| |____htmlwidgets
| | |____.DS_Store
| | |____lib
| | | |____.DS_Store
| | | |____sigma-1.0.3
| | | | |____.DS_Store
| | | | |____plugins
| | | | | |____sigma.layout.forceAtlas2.min.js
| | | | | |____sigma.parsers.gexf.min.js
| | | | | |____sigma.parsers.json.min.js
| | | | | |____sigma.plugins.animate.min.js
| | | | | |____sigma.plugins.dragNodes.min.js
| | | | | |____sigma.plugins.filter.min.js
| | | | | |____sigma.plugins.neighborhoods.min.js
| | | | | |____sigma.renderers.customShapes.min.js
| | | | | |____sigma.statistics.HITS.min.js
| | | | |____README.md
| | | | |____sigma.min.js
| | |____sigma.js
| | |____sigma.yaml
|____LICENSE
|____NAMESPACE
|____R
| |____sigma.R
|____README.md
|____sigma.Rproj
```

The tutorial doesn't say anything about the files `sigma.parsers.gexf.min.js` and `sigma.min.js`. I would have guessed, just like the NPM world, those would be installed with a command using `sigma.yaml` before building the project.

I followed the steps, and the project ran; however, those dependencies didn't get added.

I thought maybe I'd installed the dependencies globally by accident; however, when I look at the [documentation for `devtools::install_github`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/devtools/versions/1.13.5/topics/install_github), I don't see parameters for local vs global.

I don't think I did anything differently than the tutorial specified...

So why does the tutorial call out for those files if it apparently doesn't need them. Or how am I supposed to get them, if they are needed?

Comment: Do you have your project on github?

Comment: What you generally do is copy the javascript library into the `inst/htmlwidgets/lib` directory. Then you tell R which javascript files to 'compile' (is that the right word?) in [the `.yaml`](https://github.com/jjallaire/sigma/blob/master/inst/htmlwidgets/sigma.yaml).

Comment: https://github.com/BBaysinger/tutorial-Creating-a-htmlwidget

Comment: Oops. Ok, fixed now.

Comment: I included the dependencies as empty .js files, just so Git would retain that structure, as I don't think it tracks empty directories.

Comment: I think the key step you're missing is "HTML widgets are always hosted within an R package" ( [source](https://www.htmlwidgets.org/develop_intro.html) ). The widget will only work once you have built the R package.

Comment: Hm. I'm still not connecting the dots. Is my package structured incorrectly? And do I have to run a script to include the dependencies, or install them manually?

Comment: Technically you don't have a package; you have a folder of R code and a folder of javascript code. A package is something you can install and run using `install.packages("yourpackage"); library(yourpackage)`, and requires at least a NAMESPACE and a DESCRIPTION file (like in jjallaire's example you link to). [Hadley's books a great resource on writing packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/intro.html).